# How to rerun failed test Python Webdriver test?

Tags: python, webdriver

I am not able to rerun my failed python webdriver test. I am using unittest for test execution.

Have tried using [flaky](https://github.com/box/flaky) but not successful.

Comment: Removed unnecessary introductions and closings.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this.

Below is the sample code for the same:

```
import HTMLTestRunner
import os
import unittest

def testsuite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest("Add your test here")


    return suite

reportloc = os.getcwd()
outfile = open(reportloc + "TestReport.html", "w")
executor = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title="Test Report", description="Tests")

envresult = executor.run(testsuite())
if envresult.error_count >= 1 or envresult.failure_count >= 1:
    executor.run(testsuite())
```

The test suite will execute again once again if either of the test case has a failure or a error.